# Read more link for blog listing page

Tags: the-content, read-more

I have a blog page setup to list posts. The "Read More" link is added by

```
 <?php
  global $more;
  $more = 0; 

  the_content('<a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>'); ?>
```

How do i add the_permalink in where the "#" is without breaking the php?

Comment: This use of `the_content()` is not very clean : only the link text should be specified here, without HTML tags. WP might remove the `<a>` tags. Could you check what outputs exactly in the source code ? Also, the "Read More" link may be handled by javascript in your theme (it's the only reason I see to put a `#` as the link source), be sure to check this as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink). Otherwise this is basically a [PHP string concatenation question](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php).

```
the_content('<a href="'.get_permalink().'" class="button">Read More</a>');
```